# D3 force layout: How to maintain a given minimum distance between nodes?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, force-layout

I am using force layout. New d3 nodes are created by clicking inside a div element. The node is created at the point of click. The nodes are rectangles of size 50 pixels x 50 pixels. Immediately after creating a node, I set its fixed property to true so that it does not move on its own. I am not calling force.drag. The nodes can be moved by holding down ctrl key and dragging the node. An edge can be created by dragging mouse (without holding ctrl key) from one node to the other.

Now, I want to add the following feature.
The closest distance between any two nodes should be more than a certain minimum. You can assume any positive value for the minimum distance. Let us assume 100 pixels. When any new node is created too close to an existing node, then the nodes should move so that the distance between any two nodes becomes more than 100 pixels. Similarly, when one node is moved and brought too close to another, then also the nodes should move to maintain minimum 100 pixels distance.

There is no condition on which nodes to move and in which direction. One way is to check coordinates and distances and then calculate which nodes to move, how much, in what direction and execute code accordingly. But, is there a simpler way in d3?

Comment: There's no simpler way. The force layout doesn't support specifying a minimum distance.

Answer (score 3):

Consider just using `force.linkDistance()` and `force.linkStrength()` to achieve this. linkDistance represents your minimum distance constraint, and linkStrength (in the range of [0, 1]) determines how 'rigid' the link distance is, or how much linkDistance can be overridden by the simulation.

[force.linkDistance](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-linkDistance)

[force.linkStrength](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-linkStrength)

Comment: If I use linkDistance and linkStrength, will it be must to use force.drag? And can I continue to let fixed property remain as true, or do I have to set it as false?

Comment: You won't need to use force.drag, but unfortunately fixed nodes will not respond to linkDistance, since it relies on the simulation, and fixed nodes are exempted from the simulation.